# Why does this ggplot2 graph fail to plot when looped over?

Tags: r, pdf, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a large number of graphs by looping over some data, but graphs produced when the plotting functions are encapsulated within a for loop are corrupted PDFs.

I've reduced it down to a minimal example here; this should produce 1.pdf as expected, but 2.pdf and 3.pdf generated inside the loop are slightly smaller files, and don't open in PDF reader software.

```
i <- 1

pdf(paste(i,'.pdf',sep=''))
ggplot(NULL,aes(x=i, y=i)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10)) +
  ggtitle(paste('i =', i))
dev.off()


for(i in 2:3) {
  pdf(paste(i,'.pdf',sep=''))
  ggplot(NULL,aes(x=i, y=i)) +
    geom_point() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10)) +
    ggtitle(paste('i =', i))
  dev.off()
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to print it: `print(ggplot(...))`

Comment: I think that's right (silly mistake!), but why then does it work outside the loop?

Comment: FAQ 7.22 http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_73.html